# action mailer delivred success

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

There is a way to execute code if delivred success in ActionMailer?

My case:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def action
  end
end

UserMailer.action.deliver_later!
```

How can I execute code after mail delivered?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What code are you trying to execute? Mail is delivered asynchronously - so it's probably best to trigger whatever "after-delivery" behaviour you want within the `action` method above. More specifically, after calling `mail` within that method.

Comment: I use [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to send mail asynchonously, and it allows you to implement a success hook on your job (see the `Hooks` section on the linked repo)

Answer (score 2):

You can use rails action mails observer method. [rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) - Observing and Intercepting Mails

for example you can create a mailer observer

```
class UserMailerObserver
  def self.delivered_email(mail)
    # code to be executed
  end
end
```

And then registering the observer

```
# config/initializers/mailer.rb
ActionMailer::Base.register_observer(UserMailerObserver)
```